# Shift Concrete Column by few inches

Tags: civil-engineering, concrete, foundations, columns

While building the foundation of a house, the concrete columns were built 15cm (6 inches) from the planned position, which is reducing the space for a door.

The position that should have been there is shown below. But, C2 is shifted to left by 6 inches, and the column shown at the bottom of pic is shifted 6 inches to right. This leaves no space for the door to be placed as expected. Need a workaround.

[image]

In below pic, the upper column is shifted to left by 6", and lower 6" to right, leaving just 2'6" for door rather than required 3'6".

[image]

So we need to shift the column by 6 inches. How to do it? It's built up to the ground level only yet, and beam isn't  built over it.

Comment: This seems like something that you should run by the building's structural engineer.

Comment: I agree with JMac that, regardless of whatever answers may appear here, you'll need to check with the building's structural engineers (the one who did the math and the one at the jobsite). That being said, we'll need more information to give any sort of answer, such as the total number of floors in the building, the height per floor and what the building's purpose is.

Comment: It's Math was done by me, and I made a mistake in calculation in the foundation plan which led to the problem. Total number of floors are 4, height per floor is 11' and the building is a simple residential house. If column details are needed, I will share that too. Please let me know.